# Citrix on OS X - GlobalSign certificate errors

Tags: macos

I trying to access a work Citrix server using my MacBook pro. I can log in fine with a windows machine, but when I try from my mac I get an error.

What should I do to fix this? I have't found much information via Google.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to install the intermediate SSL Certificate on your server. Please check your SSL Certificate installation online: https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/